# Компонента Image в среде Builder6.0 C++

Tags: c++builder

Нужен **пример** построения графика функций в этой компоненте.
Желательно к этой функции:

> 3x(в кубе)-4х(в квадрате)+2x-3=у

Помогите кто чем может, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](http://files.mail.ru/WLT3B4) вам похожая лабораторка и похожая задача. Делала не я, а мой преподаватель: Андриянец Алеся Чеславовна.